# How do I prompt for offline access in the oauth2 playground?

Tags: oauth2-playground

I have set access type to "offline" in the playground settings, but I'm not being prompted for offline access, just for access to my contacts (which is the scope I selected). How can I make it prompt for offline access?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, asking for "Offline" access will make sure that you get a Refresh Token on Step 2.

There used to be a message to the user in the authorization prompt about this but it seems this message no longer is displayed in these cases.